# Database link not working

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, href

I have a problem with [this page](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/list.php?id=FREE)

the green go logo next to the image is meant to visit the promotions site saved on my database. But it loads the same page in a new tab.

My code for this is:

```
<a href="<?php echo $data['promo_link']; ?>" target="_blank"><img alt="" title="" src="GO.png" height="50" width="50" align="right" /></a>
```

Any ideas why it does not work?

If you need any code for any of my pages then please let me know and I will edit this and add it.

Thanks.

**HOW DO I HREF MY GO IMAGE TO A LINK SAVED UNDER** promo_link **IN MY DATABASE TABLE?**

```
  <?php

include_once('include/connection.php');
include_once('include/article.php');

$article = new article;


**if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $id = $_GET['id'];
$data = $article->fetch_data($id);**

$articles = $article->fetch_all();

?>

<html>

<head>
<title>xclo mobi</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="other.css" />
</head>

<body>
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>


<div class="container">
<a href="index.php" id="logo">Category = ???</a>


    <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { 
    if ($article['promo_cat'] === $_GET['id']) { ?>


<div class="border">
<a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $article['promo_title']; ?>" style="text-decoration: none">
<img src="<?php echo $article['promo_image']; ?>" border="0" class="img" align="left"><br />


**<a href="<?php echo $data['promo_link']; ?>" target="_blank"><img alt="" title="" src="GO.png" height="50" width="50" align="right" /></a>**
<br /><br /><br /><br />
          <font class="title"><em><center><?php echo $article['promo_title']; ?></center></em></font>

<br /><br />

<font class="content"><em><center><?php echo $article['promo_content']; ?></center></em></font>

</div><br/><br />

          </a>

 <?php } } } ?>

</div>
<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `href` attribute is empty and because you're using `target="_blank"` clicking on the link will open the same page in a different tab.

The `$data['promo_link']` is empty. I can't tell why because there is no code.

**Edit**

It seems you forgot the brackets

replace `$article = new article;` with `$article = new article();`

also `$article->fetch_data($id)` is probably returning an empty value.

As I can see, your id value is "FREE". make sure that `article->fetch_data("FREE")` returns what you expecting it to return.

I also suggest changing you code style.
This is much more easy to read:

```
if ($param){
    echo '<div>' . $data["bla"] . '</div>';
}
```

mixing your PHP code and yout HTML code makes it hard to read and understand.

Note: `<font class="title"><em><center><?php echo $article['promo_title']; ?></center></em></font>` is deprecated. Use CSS:

HTML/PHP code:

```
echo '<div class="title">' . $article['promo_title'] . '</div>';
```

And the CSS:

```
.title{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: That is my only code regarding that. This is the same code for the download link on this [link](http://www.xclo.co.uk/mobile/appdonate/article.php?id=1)

Comment: So how else can I href my image to a database field?

Comment: Locate the place you're giving a value to the $data['promo_link'] parameter. See what went wrong there.

Comment: I really do not know. It works well on the single.php page (click an offer logo) but not on list.php both have the value of $data = $article->fetch_data($id); on the page so why does it not work on one page but it works on another?

Comment: There are 2 options. 1 - the $id is wrong. 2 - the fetch_data function relies on something that appears in the first case but not in the second. Add the whole code, it is impossible to help you this way.

Comment: Add what? My whole list.php and single.php pages? Seems a bit strange when displayed what is involved with these 2 pages. Or do you want the article code?

Comment: hmmm. I have implemented your codes but it still does not work.

Comment: Sorry, can't do it that way. 1. you have to understand a little php and mysql or the framework you work with, otherwise you won't be able to do anything. 2 - When you ask a question you need to give as much details as possible. You should do some "investigation" before, like trying to understand what values you get or what error message.

Comment: i never got an error message other wise i would have investigated it as my reporting is turned on to e-all so i would have seen an error. the answer was simple it was $article and NOT $data. it took someone else to pick it up. thanks for your help.